# "Could not load file or assembly System.Device.Gpio" on iot edge

Tags: c#, gpio, azure-iot-edge

Tried to make a simple demo of using Gpio in C# on a Raspberry Pi with Azure Iot Edge. Included System.Device.Gpio" Version="0.1.0-prerelease.19171.3" in the project and it compiles perfectly and generates the docker module. But when the module starts on the Rasberry pi, I get an exception "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Device.Gpio, Version=0.1.0.0 ..."

Custom module in C# on Azure IOT Edge for Raspberry Pi (newest release using apt-get). Build with Visual Studio Code and Azure IoT Edge for Visual Studio Code. 
The module works fine when I am not using the Gpio library.

Module.csproj

```
…
<PackageReference Include="System.Device.Gpio" Version="0.1.0-prerelease.19171.3" />
…
```

Program.cs

```
…
using System.Device.Gpio;
…
using (var controller = new GpioController()){
  controller.OpenPin(17, PinMode.Output);
  controller.Write(17, PinValue.High)
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the assembly isn't being copied when you run the app on the RPi.  Open the project references, right-click the Gpio assembly and open Properties.  Make sure that "Copy Local" is set to True.

Comment: Is this the same error as yours? https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/345

Comment: @silent: Yes; it is probably the same problem. Thanks for the link.