# "Root element is missing" using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, raspberry-pi

I am running a C# application on the raspberry pi in which i read an xml file once at startup and then each time the file changes using this code:

```
using System.Xml;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(settingsFileName);
```

The first time (at startup) it always works, however when the file changes i always get this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
```

The config file looks like:

```
<config>
  <data1 seconds = "5000"></data1>
  <data2 check = "16:00"></data2>
  <data3 max = "50"></data3>
</config>
```

and off course i only change data and not the root element "config".

What could be causing this?

EDIT:

Putting `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top of the file improves a little, now it only gives the error the second time i change the file.

There is no code that changes the file, there is however code that checks the last saved time of the file and if that is different compared to the initial one, then i read the xml file again. The actual change of the xml file I do myself with the default editor of winscp (as i am using SSH to access the pi).

`dotnet --version 3.1.425`

Comment: Consider putting `<?xml version="1.0"?> ` at the top of your XML file; that might fix it.

Comment: _however when the file changes i always get this exception_ - What are the contents of the file (raw string) when it changes? Where's the code that changes the XML?

Comment: You wouldn't get that error if you weren't breaking the xml structure. How are you changing the file?

Comment: What version of Net/Core are you using?  May be related to following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944145/filenotfoundexception-using-gpio-nuget-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: As requested previously, can you share the file contents if read as a string?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry i needed some time to get your point. It seems indeed that string is empty. So this has nothing to do with xml.  I added a small delay between detecting the file has changed and reading it again, and this solves the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Adding a time is just a kludge.  What version of Net/Core are you using?